# Is this a simple answer to the classic problem "A certain city has 10 bus routes..."

Tags: graph-theory, math-history

[image]

A certain city has 10 bus routes. Is it possible to arrange the routes and the bus stops so that if one route is closed, it is still possible to get from anyone stop to any other (possibly changing along the way), but if any two routes are closed, there are at least two stops such that it is impossible to get from one to the other?

Given the solution above, why did the authors feel compelled to answer: Yes. Consider 10 straight lines in the plane, no 2 are parallel & no 3 are concurrent. Let lines be bus routes & let points of intersection be stops. We get from anyone stop to any other (if the stops lie on 1 line, w/o changing; & if not, then with just 1 change). If we discard 1 line, it's still possible to get from anyone stop to any other, changing buses at most once. However, if we discard 2 lines, then 1 stop-their point of intersection-will have no bus routes passing thru it, & it'll be impossible to get from this stop to any other.

Source: A. M. Yaglom and l. M. Yaglom
CHALLENGING MATHEMATICAL
PROBLEMS WITH
ELEMENTARY SOLUTIONS
Volume II
Problems From Various Branches of Mathematics
Translated by James McCawley, Jr.
Revised and edited by Basil Gordon
DOVER PUBLICATIONS, INC.
NEW YORK

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct.

Comment: My guess, Joe, is that when they wrote "changing", they meant "changing once".

Comment: Your answer is correct and fine. It is possible the authors just didn't think of this solution and thus put their solution into the book. Everybody overlooks something every now and then.

Comment: My solution fails to meet the requirement, "If we discard 1 line, it's still possible to get from anyone stop to any other, changing buses at most once."

Comment: Gerry, your interpretation of the wording is what makes the problem sufficiently complex. Thanks.

Comment: Shubham is wrong, my answer is incorrect because I did not comply with all of the requirements of the problem. In my opinion, Gerry answered my question, "Why did the authors feel compelled...impossible to get from this stop to any other."

Comment: Auscrypt is wrong, presumably for the same reason Shubham is wrong. How do I unmark Auscrypt as correct and mark Gerry's as correct. (remember, I did not ask for the answer, just the justification for the complexity of the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s go back to the roots.

I guess this is a problem 101 at p.53 from a book “Non-elementary problems in elemntary presentation” by A.M. Yaglom & A.M. Yaglom (“Неэлементарные задачи в элементарном изложении” by Акива Моисеевич и Исаак Моисеевич Яглом), Moskow, State publishing house of technical and theoretical literature, 1954.

[image]

It is the same problem which you quoted and your solution fits for it.

Also author’s solution is the same which your quoted.

[image]

I can explain the situation as follows. The problem is contained in a subsection devoted to arrangements of points and planes and the authors say that this topic was developed in XIX century into a big science, called *projective geometry*. The questions, considered in problems 101–107 belong to relatively narrow topic of projective geometry, namely, to so-called *configuration theory*, which has a big importance in modern mathematics. This explains the solution, but it is still surprising how your simple  solution was missed.

But I guess that this problem probably was taken from Moskow mathematical competition from 1950 (9-10 forms, second round, problem 4):

> Можно ли провести в городе $10$ автобусных маршрутов и установить на них остановки так, что какие бы $8$ маршрутов ни были взяты, найдётся остановка, не лежащая ни на одном из них, а любые $9$ маршрутов проходят через все остановки.
>
> (Given a city, can we arrange $10$ bus routes and set bus stops on them such that for each 8 routes there is a bus stop not belonging to any of the routes, but each $9$ routes contain all stops).

The proposed solution is the same as Yagloms’:

> Проведём $10$ попарно пересекающихся прямых, никакие три из которых не пересекаются в одной точке. Пусть маршруты проходят по этим прямым, а остановками служат точки пересечения прямых. Любые $9$ маршрутов проходят через все остановки, поскольку через каждую остановку, лежащую на оставшейся прямой, проходит одна из $9$ прямых, соответствующих этим маршрутам. Любые $8$ маршрутов не проходят через остановку, которая является точкой пересечения оставшихся двух маршрутов.

But although this problem looks similar to Yagloms’, its essence is different! It asks not about connectivity of a graph with removed edges, but about incidence requirements. The geometric solution satisfies them, whereas the cyclic graph doesn’t.